# Is it acceptable to return HTML from an accessor?

Tags: php, laravel, dry

I'm using Laravel framework.  Wherever possible I use the model to return common properties that may be used throughout the application.

Part of my application tracks response times of websites (Time To First Byte/TTFB).  Within my `Website` model I 'grade' the response times as 'good', 'bad' and 'average'.  So, I have an accessor that returns this.  Pretty straightforward, and good practice:

```
/**
 * Accessor for TTFB grade (good, bad, average).
 * 
 * @return String
 */
public function getAverageTtfbGradeAttribute()
{
    if($this->average_ttfb < 0.5) {
        $grade = 'good';
    } elseif($this->average_ttfb >= 0.5 && $this->average_ttfb < 1.2) {
        $grade = 'average';
    } else {
        $grade = 'bad';
    }

    return $grade;
}
```

Throughout the app I want to display the TTFB/response time, but I want it coloured based off the grade.  I have created another accessor that relies on the first accessor:

```
/**
 * Accessor for TTFB with a colour
 * 
 * @return String
 */
public function getAverageTtfbColoredAttribute()
{
    $str = '<span class="';

    if($this->averageTtfbGrade == 'good') {
        $str.= 'text-success';
    } elseif($this->averageTtfbGrade == 'average') {
        $str.= 'text-warning';
    } else {
        $str.= 'text-danger';
    }

    $str.= '">' . $this->average_ttfb .'s</span>';

    return $str;
}
```

To use this I just need to use `$website->averageTtfbColored`.  It works perfectly.

My question though is whether this is good or bad practice?  My understanding is that HTML should never be part of business logic whether that's in a controller, model or any other part of your application.  However, if I follow that logic then I will end up with if-statements in views which will be repeated in numerous places in my application - it goes against the DRY principal.

What's best practice here?  Am I just over thinking it?

Comment: Logic is meant to be written in the controller, the model is responsible for data retrieving and basic manipulations like uppercasing strings etc. And views should show the data with minimal amount of if conditions. That is the pattern I follow, don't know if it's what you're expecting.

Comment: Well that's the different between fat controller, skinny model and vice versa.  That's not really the question.  I can move this logic from the model to a controller but the problem has then been moved from the view to the controller and then I have 2 issues; HTML in a controller and it's repeated a ton of times.  With what I have now I have this logic in a model, that is used all over the app but only written once.  The only downside is that it has HTML in it, which is generally a no-no.  I guess the real question is whether this use-case is an acceptable exception

Comment: @ImmortalDude I disagree with you. The model layer (as opposed to models in MVC) should contain the business logic, and the view layer should handle the presentation, with the controllers being as skinny as possible. Fat controllers are a common antipattern and make for an application that's difficult to maintain and test.

Comment: @MatthewDaly `as opposed to models in MVC` I'm following that exact pattern, I don't disagree with your pattern, it's just that I follow the pattern you don't follow, just my opinion, not a hard core "way" to write code in the mvc pattern

Comment: @ImmortalDude The model layer is not the same thing as the model classes the Framework provides eg Eloquent. The M in MVC encompasses not just something like Eloquent but also any other business logic, eg if your application sends push notifications,  that functionality should be wrapped in a service class. Moving that sort of functionality to controllers is a recipe for bloated, repetitive code that's hard to test, and has bitten me very hard in the past. If a controller method is longer than about 10 lines, you should always consider moving some of the functionality to the model layer.

Answer (score 0):

That violates the MVC pattern as your models are also partially views now. I would suggest that you create a few small subviews/components like `/resources/views/components/averageTtfd.blade` and then use those throughout the app.

Comment: That could work.  Seems a little overkill to have an entire view that outputs a single number wrapped in a span, but I guess it's cleaner than having it in the model.  Thanks

Comment: It might be a little overkill, but that's a small price to pay for keeping the code structured.

Answer (score 0):

I think logically anything that generates HTML is part of the view layer and therefore doesn't really belong on the model.

You're right that it shouldn't be repeated in the view layer too, though. Alternative methods include:

- Create a partial to render the item
- Create a helper function to return the right values
- Create a view model to handle this logic

The latter option is the most complex and not natively included in Laravel, but there are third party implementations around.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for getting the value on a Model is completely right, it’s known as rich entities, but you application might not be always running over http, which means html code doesn’t make sense on a model, you can easily create a blade template just for this.

A few other small suggestions. use early return and avoid else/elseif